# Too many DB connections while using hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, spring, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and spring. We've a spring based service, which is using oracle database using hibernate. This service is deployed to 4 hosts.

We have one external java client which is using our service. It makes about ~40 service calls per second. So ideally there should be at most 40(calls)*4(hosts)=160 open connections. But for some reason, the DB connections used by our service grow even more than 600.

Can we set up some metrics for checking the leak in DB connections? How can we find out these leak connections?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using 3rd party jars for connection polling then you can enable their logging and set logAbandoned property to true. So it will log your all logAbandoned connections.

As shown below -

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${dataSource.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${dataSource.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${dataSource.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${dataSource.password}" />
        <property name="validationQuery" value="${datasource.validationQuery}" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="${datasource.maxActive}" />
        <property name="maxIdle" value="${datasource.maxIdle}" />
        <property name="maxWait" value="${datasource.maxWait}" />
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" />
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true" />      
        <property name="minIdle" value="${datasource.minIdle}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="${datasource.initialSize}" />
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="${datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis}" />
        <property name="logAbandoned" value="${datasource.logAbandoned}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Since I'm using c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource, it says logAbandoned is invalid property.

Comment: I am using Tomcat pool so property is there. There definitely must be some property to log abandoned connection. You will have to explore c3p0 properties more.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a connection pool with Hibernate, then your pool provider might be keeping a lot of connections around, even if they are not being used. In case of c3po, check the `connection.minPoolSize` and `connection.maxPoolSize` properties.

Comment: I have min and max pool size setup in my config:
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />

Comment: try setting maxPoolSize to 1 for once and see if it makes the problem go away.

Answer (score 0):

My datasource bean looks like this:

```
<bean id="fssDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass">
         <util:property-path path="FSSConfiguration.driverName"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jdbcUrl">
        <util:property-path path="FSSConfiguration.url" />
    </property>
    <property name="user">
            <util:property-path path="FSSConfiguration.username" />
    </property>
    <property name="password">
            <util:property-path path="FSSConfiguration.password" />
    </property>
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="240" />
    <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="60000" />
    <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="0" />
    <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000" />
    <property name="debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces" value="true" />
    <property name="unreturnedConnectionTimeout" value="300" />
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="1" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
</bean>
```

Can you please validate?

Comment: please add it to a question, not as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add following appenders in your log4j.xml and all c3p0 logs will be directed to ${catalina.home}/logs/c3poLog.log file -

```
<appender name="c3poLogs" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG"/>
    <param name="Append" value="true"/>
    <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/c3poLog.log"/>
    <!--<param name="DatePattern" value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>-->
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
    </layout>
</appender>


<category name="com.mchange.v2" additivity="false">
    <priority value="${log4j.category.com.mchange.v2}"/>
    <appender-ref ref="c3poLogs"/>
</category>
```